# How to bring undead back to real life?

Tags: biology, magic, life

This question is a very close to question [How could a mummy come back to life?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/how-could-a-mummy-come-back-to-life), but I hope that not duplicate.

Undead = alive, because dead = after death, un = negation. But they are alive in a bit different way.

How to bring undead to real life? My question is based on czech movie [Ať žijí duchové (Long Live Ghosts!)](https://www.csfd.cz/film/5982-at-ziji-duchove) ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075703/)).

There *young* ghost girl (she is about 11 years old, but for more than 400 years of ghost life) accepts flower (exactly daisy) to get real life back.

I used a different way, to take very magic armor (made of scales of white dragon, one of the most magical being in the Old world) on.

And I think what else way could be used to bring undead back to real life. And of course, I accept that some undead (like skeletons or zombies) probably cannot be brought back to real life.

Comment: All forms of answer in this question will need to be based on a form of "magic" so they are all going to depend on how well you sell this magic in the context of the story.

Comment: Given your tags and your description, the short answer is going to be "magic". You haven't provided any information about what undead are like in your fictional world, or what magic is like. EDIT: @A.C.A.C. beat me to it!

Comment: Agreeing with the other commenters, the answer is "any way you want," since you're permitting magic and haven't assigned any limits on magic.  I might recommend a different approach.  **Why** do you want the dead to come back to life, and **what** does that phrase mean to you?  Bringing the dead back to life is a *very* powerful think in literature.  Make sure you *really* get your money's worth.  Bringing the dead back to life "because you feel like it" or "to make the ending happier" is going to ring hollow.  What message do you want to convey to the reader about life/death?

Comment: Understanding that message would do quite a lot to scope the magical process you put in place.  It won't be enough to save this question (which will remain terribly broad), but it could get you started on answering the question yourself.

Comment: For an example of what happens when you don't have good answers to that **why** and **what** questions, consider [The Death and Return of Superman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PlwDbSYicM).  It's a pseudo-documentary on what happens when you break the barrier between dead and alive in a story setting.

Answer (score 3):

A scifi way to bring them to life is to inject them before they die with a virus that changes their DNA and make each cell "cristalize" after death instead of liquify.

Just like the Water bears.

Then after they die, you somehow activate them back to life with some sort of radiation that decristalize all cells at exactly the same time. They should come back alive like they didn't die.

This is not the same as cryogenic sleep, because you do the DNA change preamtivly.

You can change the DNA by mistake so you mess them up when they wake up from the dead.

Otherwise how could this be a good scifi if they wake up well?

Comment: [Crypstobiosis?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptobiosis)

Comment: Yes :) couldn't find the word.

Comment: Yea! Sea monkeys! :)

Answer (score 1):

Resurrection.

What's the difference?

My God said Mr Mummy is ok.

You creepy scientists with your Tesla coils and grave robbing archaeologists think you can play God. That's not cool.

But if my God does it it's gotta be cool. Cause, you know, God.

By the way, "real" zombies were social outcasts who were outcast by having a funeral for them. And you thought your friends and family inviting you to a party that turns out to be an intervention was harsh.

So, unless my God says it's cool, dead to me is dead to me. Sorry Mr.  Heathen.